# Is the live block connection to go into the STC1000 correct?

Tags: neutral

The red wire goes into the live block of the STC1000 that I am working with (on the other end.) As I understand it, the red wire should be attached to the right pin (left in the image) of the plug. However the local electrician tells me my current connection as shown in the photo is correct.

Can someone take a look and confirm that the connection is correct with respect to the live block connection?

[image: Plug and Switch Connection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from your image: Black is Neutral, Red is live, Green is ground. The left part I suppose is a switch. Everything OK, but the lamp will always glow, if you need to glow only when switched on, then you should connect it to black & blue wire.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on light! All works fine now. Thanks.